# "broken pipe" after every terminal command

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

I’m running Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) with [iTerm2](http://iterm2.com) and [Oh-My-Zsh](http://ohmyz.sh). After every command I run—even if the command is successful—I receive the error “broken pipe.” How can I troubleshoot what is outputting this error so that I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, if you run `setopt xtrace` in a *zsh* session or start *zsh* with `zsh -x`, *zsh* will print each command and its arguments as it is executed, including the internal ones used to set up the prompt or other hook functions.

This will probably create a lot of output as *oh-my-zsh* may run quite a few functions just to display the prompt. It will look something like this:

```
[...]
+__config.git:9> return 1
+__tempdirs:1> emulate -L zsh
+__tempdirs:2> setopt extendedglob
+__tempdirs:3> setopt nullglob
+__tempdirs:4> local -a match mbegin mend
+__tempdirs:5> [[ d == d ]]
+__tempdirs:6> [[ /home/adaephon == (#b)(/tmp/foo/)([^/]##)* ]]
+__tempdirs:10> return 1
+xtermtitle:5> local 'preamble=pts/32 adaephon@tau: '
+xtermtitle:6> local 'cl='
[...]
```

Each line is prefixed with the value of `PROMPT4`, which by default is `+%N:%i>`. `%N` stands for the name of the script, sourced file or function, `%i` for the line number. The rest ist the command as it is run, that is after all substitutions and expansions.

For example:

```
+__tempdirs:6> [[ /home/adaephon == (#b)(/tmp/foo/)([^/]##)* ]]
```

refers to the 6th line of some script or function named `__tempdirs`. Looking for this line in my zsh configuration I find:

```
        if [[ $2 = (#b)(/tmp/foo/)([^/]##)* ]]; then
```

In my configuration `__tempdirs` in an element of the `zsh_directory_name_functions`, which is a list of functions *zsh* uses for dynamic directory naming. As the present working directory is shown as part of my normal prompt, it is run each time before the prompt is displayed.

In your case the error message "broken pipe" will be just under the lines where the error occurs. The elements of piped commands are usually first printed line by line followed by the output, but it may get a bit complicated:

```
tau% setopt xtrace
tau% echo foo | sed 's/o/u/g' | (sed 's/u/a/g' ; echo bar) | sed 's/a/e/g' 
+zsh:4> echo foo
+zsh:4> sed s/o/u/g
+zsh:4> sed s/u/a/g
+zsh:4> sed s/a/e/g
fuu
+zsh:4> echo bar
ber
tau%
```

Comment: Awesome answer! Thanks! So, it's happening in my theme file while executing the grep portion of this line:

**if 'hg st | grep -Eq "^\?"'; then**

Now I just have to figure out why.